# Issue with a Laravel complex where condition. | Issue with CakePHP join

Tags: laravel-5, join, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables :

> TableA, TableB.

TableA has following columns :

> id, username, password, type, TableB_id

TableB has following columns :

> id, type, some_column, some_other_column

**Now I need the records of TableA using TableB on the basis of TableB's id and 'type'.**

I'm trying to define something like this in my model

TableA Model :

```
$this->belongsTo('TableB', [
    'foreignKey' => 'TableB_id',
]);
```

TableB Model :

```
$this->belongsTo('TableA', [
    'foreignKey' => 'id',
]);
```

When I print the SQL query it provides me this result :

> ON
>       TableA.id = (TableB.id)

But I need this :

> ON
>       TableA.TableB_id = (TableB.id)

================== Question 2 ==================

I am trying to get following query dynamically in **Laravel**

> select * from `products` where (`category` like '%categoryOne%' OR `category` like '%categoryTwo%')  and (`brand` like '%brandOne%' OR `brand` like '%brandTwo')

Here my columns are in array. I have tried like this :

```
$query = DB::table('products');
foreach($all as $category => $subCategory){
    foreach($subCategory as $key => $value){
        $val = '%' .$key .'%';
        $users->orWhere($category, 'like', $val);
    }
}
```

Issue with this query is that it is generating all the conditions with **OR** due to **orWhere**.

Does anyone know how to get a complex query of AND, OR conditions in Laravel?

Comment: Oh, you need to hire a programmer. Or at least try your own code and post it here searching help

Comment: *"I need jQuery code for this"*. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: @Roy,
I was very new to Stackoverflow and didn't know how to ask a good question. Now stack has blocked my account from asking further questions. I'll try to modify this question. Let's see the ban got lifted or not.
Anyway thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to do. Please ignore css issues.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.classToChangeDisable').hide();
  $('.classToChange').change(function(){
      $('.classToChangeDisable').hide();
      $(this).siblings('.classToChangeDisable').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="classToChange" /> 1st
<br />
<div class="classToChangeDisable">
<input type="radio" /> 1st Sub
</div>
<br />
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="classToChange" /> 2st
<br />
<div class="classToChangeDisable">
<input type="radio" /> 2nd Sub
</div>
<br />
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="classToChange" /> 3st
<br />
<div class="classToChangeDisable">
<input type="radio" /> 3rd Sub
</div>
<br />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sub radio button should be hidden not disabled.
rest is perfect.

Comment: Check edit. Ignore CSS issue ... i can not help with that...  :P